# Русский текст в консоли Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, кодировка, creator

Здравствуйте. Сначала мы учились С на dev-cpp. Там у меня была русифицирована консоль. Все производилось через изменение файла в настройках. Вот мы перешли на Qt Creator и нам зачем-то сказали все проги переписать на Qt Creator. Т.к. текст для консоли в них был на русском, Qt Creator выдает мне кракозябры. Подскажите, можно ли каким-нибудь способом включить поддержку русского текста в консоли? например, тоже подключением какого-нибудь файла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите в сторону QString::fromUtf8 для Линукса , для винды это, наверное, QString::fromLocal8Bit (не пробовал если честно)

Answer (score 2):

Мне помог следующий код, с кодировкой уж поиграйтесь сами:

```
#include <clocale>
#include <Windows.h>

setlocale(LC_ALL, "PL_pl.UTF-8");
SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8);
SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
```